# Debug formatting code

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm trying to debug my code here:

```
 private void CheckFormatting()
    {
        StringReader objReaderf = new StringReader(txtInput.Text);
          List<String> formatTextList = new List<String>();

                 do
                     {
                         formatTextList.Add(objReaderf.ReadLine());
                     } 
                 while (objReaderf.Peek() != -1);

                 objReaderf.Close();
                 for (int i = 0; i < formatTextList.Count; i++)
                 {
                     if (!Regex.IsMatch(formatTextList[i],
                         "G[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2} JG[0-9]{2}"))
                     {
                         MessageBox.Show("Line " + formatTextList[i] + " is not formatted correctly.",
                             "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
                         break;
                     }
                     else
                     {
                         this.WriteToFile();
                         MessageBox.Show("Your entries have been saved.", "Saved",
                             MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
                     }
                 }
    }
```

what it is supposed to do is to check each line in the list. if one of them isn't formatted correctly, then break the loop and display a message box, if all the lines are formatted properly then it should call the WriteToFile method. However, when testing it using a mix of input that was and was not correctly formatted it called the WriteToFile method before it displayed the error message and broke the loop. Anyone figure out why? There's some rep points in it for you :)

Thanks in advance

Examples:

These are correctly formatted:

```
G20:49:02:10 JG07
G37:84:73:20 JG48
```

This is not correctly formatted:

```
G47:29:js:20 JG29
```

If the user inputs

```
G20:49:02:10 JG07
G47:29:js:20 JG29
G37:84:73:20 JG48
```

then the code should test the first line, see that it is correctly formatted, move on to the second line, see that is not formatted properly and break the loop and display the error message.

Answer

```
   private void CheckFormatting()
    {
        StringReader objReaderf = new StringReader(txtInput.Text);
          List<String> formatTextList = new List<String>();

                 do
                     {
                         formatTextList.Add(objReaderf.ReadLine());
                     } 
                 while (objReaderf.Peek() != -1);

                 objReaderf.Close();

                 bool FlagCheck = true;

                 for (int i = 0; i < formatTextList.Count; i++)
                 {
                     if (!Regex.IsMatch(formatTextList[i],
                         "G[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2} JG[0-9]{2}"))
                     {
                         FlagCheck = false;
                         break;
                     }
                 }
                 if (FlagCheck == true)
                 {
                     this.WriteToFile();
                     MessageBox.Show("Your entries have been saved.", "Saved",
                         MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
                 }
                 else
                 {
                     MessageBox.Show("Line " + formatTextList[i] + " is not formatted correctly.",
                            "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
                 }
    }
```

Thanks mmyers

Comment: two questions: Did you intentionally leave the last { open? or did you mean to do {2} instead of just {2? second how about showing the test you think should have matched the regex or explaining what the reg ex is suppossed to match. With out knowing the requirements it's very hard to tell you why your code is not a successful implementation of them

Comment: @Rune - see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3007972/how-to-check-user-input-for-correct-formatting for why the OP is using that particular regex

Comment: The WriteToFile method should be outside the loop, or else you'll write it once for each valid line.

Comment: no i didn't, i edited that just now to reflect that.

i'll post an example ;)

Comment: @mmyers - Blast! How do i call make the loop call the WriteToFile method after it is finished then?

Comment: I would keep a boolean flag indicating whether all lines passed (initialize it to true and set to false if one fails), and if it's still true after the loop is done, then call WriteToFile.

Comment: @mmyers - that did the trick! thanks a lot. Write your answer up properly and i'll rep and tick your answer.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you're missing a closing brace in your regex: "G[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2} JG[0-9]{2".

Comment: Your right i was. i'll edit that now. However, even after correcting that it still doesn't work. it seems to run the WriteToFile method BEFORE the formatting test.

Answer (score 1):

This code is better :

```
        private void CheckFormatting ()
        {
            StringReader objReaderf = new StringReader (txtInput.Text);
            List<String> formatTextList = new List<String> ();

            do {
                formatTextList.Add (objReaderf.ReadLine ());
            } while (objReaderf.Peek () != -1);

            objReaderf.Close ();

            bool testSucceed = true;
            for (int i = 0; i < formatTextList.Count; i++) {
                if (!Regex.IsMatch (formatTextList[i], "G[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2} JG[0-9]{2}")) {
                    MessageBox.Show ("Line " + formatTextList[i] + " is not formatted correctly.", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
                    testSucceed = false;
                    break;
                }
            }

            if (testSucceed) {
                this.WriteToFile ();
                MessageBox.Show ("Your entries have been saved.", "Saved", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
            }
        }
```

Comment: yh mmyers thought of using a boolean flag too.

but you have to move the messagebox to an "else" part of the boolean if test. otherwise it wont work properly. see my edit.

some rep for you though, for getting it right.